# SQL count row where progres not done

Tags: sql, mariadb

Need some help, dont know the keyword of this problem to search online

I want to count some progres that isn't done

[image: table-example]

when progres has step3 then its not counted

desired result from that example is 2, im trying to do it alone, and it doesnt work

help is needed, Thanks Ahead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method uses `count(distinct)` and filters in the `where` clause:

```
select count(distinct progres)
from t
where not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.progres = t.progres and t2.step = 'step3');
```

Another fun way uses a difference:

```
select count(distinct progres) - count(distinct case when step = 'step3' then progres end)
from t;
```

If `'step3'` can appear at most once per `progres`, the above can be simplified to:

```
select count(distinct progres) - sum(step = 'step3')
from t;
```

Or using set operations:

```
select count(*)
from ((select progres from t)
      except  -- removes duplicates
      (select progres from t where step = 'step3')
     ) t;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
select
  count(distinct progress)
  -
  (select count(*) from t where step = 'step3')
from t
```